# Match case in Scala with tail

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

I'm new to Scala and finding the below code hard to understand. It would be really helpful if you guys can explain me in simple words what parseArguments is doing for "--config-path" and what is ::path::tail doing. we are getting scala.MatchError: None (of class scala.None$) error when we are trying to match variable configPathArg.

Here we are passing value to --config-path when we are submitting the spark-submit command but we got none matching error. Could you please let me know why it is giving error even though we are passing value to --config-path?

Thanks in advance :)

```
def parseArguments(map: Map[String, String], list: List[String]): Map[String, String] = { list match {
        case Nil => map
        case ("--config-path" | "-cp") :: path :: tail =>
          parseArguments(map ++ Map(configPathArg -> path), tail)
        case unknown :: tail =>
          parseArguments(map, tail)
        }
      }

val arguments = parseArguments(Map(), args.toList)
arguments.get(configPathArg) match {
case some(configPath: String) =>
 val is = hfs.open(new Path(configPath))
 }
```

Comment: How are you calling this code? What's `args` value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax `head :: tail` matches a `List` where the 1st element is `head` and the rest is `tail` (the rest can be empty, i.e. `Nil`).

In your case `"--config-path" :: path :: tail` means you're matching a `List` where there's at least 2 elements and the 1st one is the string `--config-path` and the second one is any value but will then be available as `path`.

- `List("--config-path", "whatever")` would match

  - and `path` would have `whatever` as value
- `List("--config-path", "whatever", ...)` would match

  - and `path` would have `whatever` as value
- `List("another string", "whatever")` would NOT match
- a list of 0 or 1 item would NOT match

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Gaeil, just one doubt here. the "path" in " "--config-path" :: path :: tail " refers to the part of the string "path" in "--config-path"? means we are comparing the list from point where we have the values like "path", is my understanding correct?

Comment: @ShivaKumar I updated my answer, hope it clarifies it.